# How can I remotely control my iMac user desktop from a Windows computer?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I know the IP address of my iMac and I have been able to ssh into the computer successfully, but I want to be able to control the desktop remotely from my Windows machine as well.  How do I enable my iMac to do this?  Is there a special program I need to use on my Windows 7 machine to do control the desktop remotely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use VNC to remotely control your Mac. There's instructions around here to turn on the built-in OS X VNC server (it's pretty straightforward), and a [Windows VNC viewer](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+vnc+viewer) (I linked to a Google search because I don't know a particular good viewer for Windows because I don't use VNC on Windows).

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to use [LogMeIn](http://www.logmein.com). It allows you to set different resolutions, you can perform Mac gestures, and it uses the least bandwidth of any remote control app I have ever used (about 10-15Kbps for a 1280x720 screen). It is cross platform too.

You create a LogMeIn account and you can either use the Windows client or the web-based client.

Comment: Another advantage of LogMeIn is that you can easily use it outside of the LAN without having to keep track of your current IP address.

Comment: Yeah, that’s awesome too. In VNC you have to know the IP of the host.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx). It has a mode to do just just that.